# Assigning only a part of a contribution to a Contribution Page

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page

Our organization just had its annual fundraising dinner/auction. People paid in one transaction for a number of things: auction items, raffle, sales tax, etc., as well as donations designated for a number of things. Most of this am recording in Civi using a Price Set with Text/Numeric Quantity for the various fields.

However, undesignated donations are going to a specific campaign that is a challenge match. I have also set up a Contribution page for this Matching Challenge. I want to be able to record the amount from only one of the price fields against this Matching Challenge Contribution Page - so the widget on our website is accurate among other reasons.

For instance, I might record this as a transaction:

```
Name: Joe
Total Amount: $175
Payment Instrument: Credit Card
Price Field: Auction = $100
Price Field: Raffle = $25
Price Field: Match donation = $50
```

So, only the $50 should be counted to the Matching Challenge contribution page.

Is there any way to do this other than making it two transactions, which could lead to confusion?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, since the link to the contribution page is determined by the source of the contribution as opposed to its individual line items, I do not believe this is currently possible. Even if you recorded two separate contributions, unless you have a corresponding contribution page for each (which would indeed be confusing as you state), they would both still be associated with the same contribution page

You may want to research alternative methods of pulling this information by line item financial type into an alternative widget - my knowledge of widgets is limited.

Hope this helps,
Tamar